# Como puedo introducir en una array de integers datos introducidos por teclado separados por un espacio

Tags: c++, array

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1,i;
    int ar[num1];
    //Introduzco la longitud de la array
    cin >> num1;
    //Meto los datos por teclado separados por esapacio
    for(i=0; i<num1; i++){
        cin>>ar[i];
    }
    //Imprimo en la consola los datos metidos en el anterior bucle
    for(i=0; i<num1; i++){
        cout << ar[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora, el fin del programa es que tu introduzcas la longitud del array y luego introduzcas los datos en la array a traves del teclado y usando espacios entre los datos.
Ejemplo de un input:

```
10

1 3 1 4 2 2 5 3 6 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que declarar el array **despues** de conocer el tamaño del mismo:

```
int num1;
std::cin >> num1;
int ar[num1];
```

En cualquier caso, los arrays deberían tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación. Este código no es portable y puede no compilar en otros sistemas. Es preferible usar `new[]`

```
int num1;
std::cin >> num1;
int * ar = new int[num1];
```